# OuterGlowBitmapEffect Alternative Without BitmapEffects

Tags: wpf, styles, effects, bitmapeffect

What is a good alternative to OuterGlowBitmapEffect?

Preferably one that can be used in a theme/style and one that can be used without BitmapEffects.

Comment: General note: The OuterGlowBitmapEffect is now (.NET 4) marked as Obsolete, and is not supported (doesn't throw anything but does nothing).

Comment: Here are some examples http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/11/04/wpf-sample-series-solution-for-the-obsolete-bitmapeffect-property-and-rendering-an-outerglowbitmapeffect/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The standard `Effect` library provides a `DropShadowEffect` that can be set up to look just like an `OuterGlowBitmapEffect`. The nice thing about this effect is that it is hardware-accelerated (unlike the bitmap effects, which are done in software). To make the `DropShadowEffect` look like a glow, simply set the `ShadowDepth` property to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Donno if is good or not, I never tested it, I just read about it, check it out [**here**](http://learnwpf.com/post/2011/03/02/Come-on-Feel-the-Noizee28093adding-noise-to-your-WPF-applications.aspx).